# Aligning items in different manner using css/flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a form right now. 
I want to make `<h>` tags align at the start of textfield and make textfields to be in the center. However, both textfield and `<h>` tags are aligned in the center now. How can I align them as I intended?

```
    <div class="vertical-offset--small inner-contact" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center">



            <h5 style="display:inline">* First Name:</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="first_name" name="first_name" ng-model="formData.first_name" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
            <br>

            <h5>* Last Name:</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="last_name" name="last_name" ng-model="formData.last_name" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
            <br>

            <h5>* Email:</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.email" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
            <br>

            <h5>* My Question:</h5>
            <textarea id="question" name="question" ng-model="formData.question" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" style="width: 90%; height: 150px;" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" required>
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div style="text-align:center">
                <button ng-click="sendEmail($event)" class="button button-form-success button--primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

On the div I'm calling following style:

```
 style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
```

Comment: Why are you using h5's anyway? The fact that you need `style="display:inline"` indicates that you should look for other elements instead. The semantic element of choice is `<label>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each of the `tags`, add the following styling:

```
h5.tag {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

See example in this snippet:

```css
h5.tag {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-offset--small inner-contact" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center">

  <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Submission from FoundVisa!" />

  <h5 style="display:inline">* First Name:</h5>
  <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="first_name" name="first_name" ng-model="formData.first_name" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
  <br>

  <h5>* Last Name:</h5>
  <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="last_name" name="last_name" ng-model="formData.last_name" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
  <br>

  <h5>* Email:</h5>
  <input type="text" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" ng-class id="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.email" style="width: 90%" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" required>
  <br>

  <h5>* My Question:</h5>
  <textarea id="question" name="question" ng-model="formData.question" ng-blur="realtimeSave()" style="width: 90%; height: 150px;" class="form-control textfield-control textfield" required>


    <div style="text-align:center">
      <button ng-click="sendEmail($event)" class="button button-form-success button--primary">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you example what do you mean by for attribute? i'm a newbie to CSS :/

Comment: Sure, no problem. I removed that part since it might have been a little confusing and will complicate the styling a bit. Ideally, input fields should have a matching `label` element. It's just a text element, basically. But you can apply the `for` attribute to associate them. So if you have an input called `name`, you set the `for` attribute of `label` to name. Here's an example: `<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" value="name">. So when you click on the label, it focuses in the input. I think you're good to leave it as is for now. But something to look into as you learn!

Comment: just note that the label for="" should point to the ID of the input rather than the value of that input - this allows screen readers to tie the label to the input: eg:<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" value="name" id="name" />